# Is there a way to execute system sp in a table valued function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to execute system stored procedure such as sp_who2 within function that returns a table ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.

Normally, you'd call `insert exec` to get the values from a stored procedure, but you can't do that in a function.